# How would you go about implementing vertical word finding in a word search solver?

Tags: javascript, html, wordsearch

I'm trying to make a more advanced project than I have before (with this project being a word search solver), and I have succeeded so far, but I got stuck when trying to implement the vertical word finding. I go about it by making lots of arrays and for loops, and that seemed to work with the horizontal, as that works well, but I can't really figure out a way to edit my code so that it works with vertical words, without getting rid of a ton of the horizontal code. I feel like it should be very easy to edit, just adding a simple value or two, but I have been working on this so long my brain is starting to hurt. Horizontal alone took forever, and I don't really want vertical to take forever, as I know it is probably very simple. My code is found below:

```js
var numberOfColumnsInput = document.getElementById('numberOfColumns');
var numberOfRowsInput = document.getElementById('numberOfRows');
var wordSearchParametersDiv = document.getElementById('wordSearchParameters')
var getInputs = document.getElementsByClassName('newInputs');
var allowStyling = document.getElementsByClassName('createdLetters');
var canConfirm = true;
var lettersArray = [];
var convertArrayToWords = []
var loopIterator = 0;
var originalLettersArray, createInputForWord,wordsToFindValue, originalLettersArrayLength, reverseWord, numberOfSpans;

function createInputs(){
  if(canConfirm == true){
    for(i=1;i<parseInt(numberOfRowsInput.value) + 1;i++){
      var newInputStuff = document.createElement("input");
      newInputStuff.setAttribute("type", "text");
      newInputStuff.setAttribute("class", "newInputs")
      newInputStuff.setAttribute("placeholder", "Enter the letters from row " + String(i))
      newInputStuff.setAttribute("maxLength", numberOfColumnsInput.value);
      wordSearchParametersDiv.appendChild(newInputStuff);
    }
    var newButton = document.createElement("button");
    newButton.setAttribute("onclick", "createWordSearch()");
    newButton.setAttribute("id", "newButtonId");
    newButton.innerHTML = 'Confirm your letters?';
    wordSearchParametersDiv.appendChild(newButton);
  }
  canConfirm = false;
}

function createWordSearch(){
  extractLetters();
  originalLettersArray = lettersArray.slice(0);
  originalLettersArrayLength = originalLettersArray.length;
  var numberOfRows = parseInt(numberOfRowsInput.value);
  var edgeOfWordSearchPosition = parseInt(numberOfColumnsInput.value);
  var createDivForSearch = document.createElement("div");
  createDivForSearch.setAttribute("class", "createdRows");
  var createSpanForLetter = document.createElement("span");
  createSpanForLetter.setAttribute("class", "createdLetters")
  for(i=0;i<numberOfRows;i++){
    var numberOfRows = parseInt(numberOfRowsInput.value);
    var edgeOfWordSearchPosition = parseInt(numberOfColumnsInput.value);
    var createDivForSearch = document.createElement("div");
    createDivForSearch.setAttribute("class", "createdRows");
    wordSearchParametersDiv.appendChild(createDivForSearch);
    for(j=0;j<edgeOfWordSearchPosition;j++){
      console.log(lettersArray);
      var createSpanForLetter = document.createElement("span");
      createSpanForLetter.setAttribute("class", "createdLetters")
      createSpanForLetter.innerHTML = lettersArray[0];
      numberOfSpans = numberOfSpans + 1;
      lettersArray.splice(0,1);
      createDivForSearch.appendChild(createSpanForLetter);
    }
  }
  createNewFindWordBox(createDivForSearch);
}

function extractLetters(){
  for(i=0;i<parseInt(numberOfRowsInput.value);i++){
    splitLetters = getInputs[i].value.split("");
    for(j=0;j<splitLetters.length;j++){
      lettersArray.push(splitLetters[j]);
    }
  }
}

function createNewFindWordBox(x){
  createInputForWord = document.createElement('input');
  var createConfirmButton = document.createElement('button');
  createInputForWord.setAttribute('class', 'wordsToFind');
  createInputForWord.setAttribute('placeholder', 'Enter a word to find it.')
  createConfirmButton.setAttribute('id', 'confirmWordButton');
  createConfirmButton.setAttribute('onClick', 'findWord()')
  createConfirmButton.innerHTML = 'Confirm Word'
  x.appendChild(createInputForWord);
  x.appendChild(createConfirmButton);
}

function findWord(){
  wordsToFindValue = createInputForWord.value;
  reverseWord = createReverse(wordsToFindValue);
  checkHorizontal();
  checkVertical();
  checkDiagonal();
  checkHorizontal('reverse');
  checkVertical('reverse');
  checkDiagonal('reverse');
}

function createReverse(x){
    var splitString = x.split("");
    var reverseArray = splitString.reverse();
    var joinArray = reverseArray.join("");
    return joinArray;
}

//Horizontal is done for now! Bug: You can find a word that has part of it on one line and the rest on another line and it will think it found a word even though that is not how word searches work.
function checkHorizontal(x){
  if(x=='reverse'){
    var whatIndexWeOn = [];
    for(i=0;i<(originalLettersArrayLength);i++){
      for(j=0;j<wordsToFindValue.length;j++){
        convertArrayToWords.push(originalLettersArray[j+i]);
        whatIndexWeOn.push(j+i);
      }
      var makeWord = convertArrayToWords.join('');
      if(makeWord == reverseWord){
        console.log('found word');
        for(j=0;j<wordsToFindValue.length;j++){
          allowStyling[whatIndexWeOn[j]].style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
        }
      }
      convertArrayToWords = [];
      whatIndexWeOn = [];
    }
  }else{
    var whatIndexWeOn = [];
    for(i=0;i<(originalLettersArrayLength);i++){
      for(j=0;j<wordsToFindValue.length;j++){
        convertArrayToWords.push(originalLettersArray[j+i]);
        whatIndexWeOn.push(j+i);
      }
      var makeWord = convertArrayToWords.join('');
      if(makeWord == wordsToFindValue){
        console.log('found word');
        for(j=0;j<wordsToFindValue.length;j++){
          allowStyling[whatIndexWeOn[j]].style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
        }
      }
      convertArrayToWords = [];
      whatIndexWeOn = [];
    }
  }
}

function checkVertical(x){
  if(x=='reverse'){

  }else{
    
  }
}

function checkDiagonal(x){
  if(x=='reverse'){

  }else{
    
  }
}
```

```css
#wordSearchParameters{
  background-color:lightgrey;
  height:50vh;
  width:90vw;
}

.newInputs{
  display:block;
}

.createdLetters{
  padding:10px;
  display:inline-block;
  border:1px black solid;
  height:25px;
  width:25px;
}

.wordsToFind{
  display:block;
}

#confirmWordButton{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Word Search Solver</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <center>
      <div id='wordSearchParameters'>
        <h1> Welcome to the Word Search Solver!</h1>
        <p>Please enter the things below:</p>
        <input type='number'id='numberOfColumns' placeholder='# of columns (vertical)'>
        <input type='number' id='numberOfRows' placeholder='# of rows (horizontal)'>
        <button id='confirmButton' onclick='createInputs()'>Confirm</button>
      </div>
    </center>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I don't have anything in the checkVertical() function yet, as that is what I need help with. I thought about copying over the horizontal code and trying to figure out what I should do from there, but I feel like there is probably a way easier way than what I would come up with. Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I would start with what's in `checkHorizontal` but note that for check horizontal you're scanning across the letters left to right (i.e., your index increases by one each time.) To do a vertical check, you'll need to increase your index by the number of columns there are.

Consider a trivial example:
A 3x3 word puzzle:

```
o n e
r g b
c o l
```

Corresponds to the following array: `[o, n, e, r, g, b, c, o, l]`

Scanning across horizontally, you could find the word `'one'`.

To find the word `'orc'` you need to start at index `i = 0`, then add the number of columns (3) to find the next letter. So assuming starting index is 0 - or the letter 'o' -  `array[previousIndex + numCols]` which equals `array[3]` gives you the next letter - `'r'` - and adding the number of columns again gives you `array[6]` or the letter `'c'`.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler solve might be in the indexing.

Save each horizontal row as just a string, then compile the vertical columns into strings.

Like

```
ABC
DEF
GHI
```

would be 3 horizontal strings, of "ABC", "DEF", "GHI" and vertical would be "ADG", "BEH", "CFI".

Diagonal strings from top right to bottom left could be done by starting with the top left, iterating across to the right, then down the right side (like "A", "BD", "CEG", "FH", "I") and then doing the same going right to left for the other diagonals.

From there, a word search would just be myArray[rowIndex].indexOf(wordToSearch), and then working out what parts of the puzzle it was from the row/indexOf result (e.g. index of 1 in vertical with indexOf returning 1, with a length of 2, would be the "EH" in the above)

I know that's not *exactly* what you were asking, but I'm a big fan of keeping things simple :)